# MSDeploy gulp build package

Tags: gulp, msdeploy

Is it possible to deploy a Single Page App project build using grunt to IIS using MSDeploy from TeamCity? The project is not any kind of Visual Studio solution and doesn't get built using MSBuild.

**My Command parameters which are not working are:**

> -source:package='%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Dist.%build.number%.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="%system.MsDeployServiceUrl%",userName="%system.UserName%",password="%system.Password%",authtype="basic",includeAcls="False"
>   -verb:sync -setParamFile:"%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Dist.%build.number%.zip.SetParameters.xml"
>   -AllowUntrusted -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="%system.WebSiteName%" -verbose

**The error I am getting is:**

> [11:47:31][Step 3/3] Error Code: ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT
>   [11:47:31][Step 3/3] More Information: Object of type 'package' and
>   path 'D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e2b0015b49d87e90\Dist.30.zip' cannot
>   be created.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.
>   [11:47:31][Step 3/3] Error: The Zip package
>   'D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e2b0015b49d87e90\Dist.30.zip' could not
>   be loaded. [11:47:31][Step 3/3] Error: Could not find file
>   'D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e2b0015b49d87e90\Dist.30.zip'.
>   [11:47:31][Step 3/3] Error count: 1. [11:47:31][Step 3/3] Process
>   exited with code -1 [11:47:31][Step 3/3] Step Deploy (Command Line)
>   failed

My build process is working as I end up with the correct artefacts, I just don't seem to be able to deploy my generated artefacts using MSDeploy

This is a screenshot of my artefacts:
[image: artefacts]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by changing my parameters to the following:

> -source:iisapp='%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\dist' -dest:iisapp='C:\www\xxxx-website',computerName="%system.MsDeployServiceUrl%",userName="%system.UserName%",password="%system.Password%",authtype="basic",includeAcls="False"
>   -verb:sync -AllowUntrusted -verbose

And changing my user to an admin user rather than an IIS user. Note use of iisapp - the key was to read the MSDeploy api using msdeploy -help

FYI - a good test is to use the intended command against msdeploy.exe in console and check output errors then push command into teamcity when it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I created a grunt and gulp plugin to do just what you are looking to do. gulp-mswebdeploy-package and grunt-mswebdeploy-package will create a ms webdeploy package from any folder and do not require your build to be running on windows.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mswebdeploy-package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mswebdeploy-package